# Vector de objetos (Duda) - C#

Tags: c#

En los siguientes 2 casos me cuesta entender el flujo de ejecución. Miren la Linea marcada con `%%%%%%%%%%%%%%` es la línea en la que se presenta mi duda,
inicialmente yo puse esa línea fuera del `for` pero obtenía un `output` en el que se devolvía solamente el último elemento del vector repetido 2 veces. Ahora bien, si bien esto está resuelto, no pude entender por qué...

Esta es mi lógica, corregidme donde me perdí o me equivoqué, cuando la línea `%%%%`  está fuera del `for`, empiezo ingresando el número 2 para generar un vector de 2, bien una vez hecho esto arranca el `for` solicitándome los datos `A.id` sigo con `A.nom` finaliza la primera vuelta con `lista[cont]=A`, OKey, arranca la segunda, se repite todo de nuevo, solo que esta vez, se reasignan los valores de `A`, por lo que cuando llega al final `lista[cont]=A`
el segundo elemento(`lista[1]`) tiene nuevos valores, y entonces, ¿Por qué desaparece `lista[0]` tomando el mismo valor que `lista[1]`?

Código:

```
int public main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("ingrese cantidad de objetos");
    int i =int.Parse( Console.ReadLine());
    servivo[] lista = new servivo[i] ;
    for (int cont = 0; cont < i; cont++)
    {
        servivo A = new servivo(); %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

        Console.WriteLine("ing id");
        A.id = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("ing nom");
        A.nom = Console.ReadLine();

        lista[cont] = A;

    }
    Console.WriteLine("Lista de objetos");

    for (int cont = 0; cont < i; cont++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(lista[cont].id);
        Console.WriteLine(lista[cont].nom);

    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

class servivo
{
    public string id;
    public string nom;
     public void respiro()
    { Console.WriteLine("puedo respirar"); }
}
```

EJEMPLO 2

```
int[] lista = new int[2];
        int var;

        for (int cont = 0; cont < 2; cont++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese valor para var");
            var=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            lista[cont] = var;
        }

        for (int cont = 0; cont < 2; cont++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lista[cont]);
        }

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenos días, si sacas la linea `servivo A = new servivo();` fuera del bucle lo que estás asignando a cada iteración al array `lista[]`es la misma referencia al mismo objeto, por eso `lista[0]`y `lista[1]` tienen los mismos valores. Es necesario que se instancie un nuevo objeto `servivo' en cada iteración (esto es, dentro del bucle) para que cada elemento asignado a 'lista' apunte a una referencia diferente. 
Puedes ver más información sobre tipos por valor y por referencia en [Tipos (Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/types)

Comment: Lei el link que me dejaste pero me cuesta entenderlo, agregue otra situacion mas simple, en la que deberia tener el mismo problema , bah no es la misma situacion, por que uno es un arreglo de int y el otro de objetos.¿podrias explicarmelo?

Comment: Los objetos son denominados tipos por referencia, esto es, cuando tu instancias una clase, lo que obtienes es un puntero o referencia a la dirección de memoria donde se encuentra el contenido de la clase. Cada vez que haces un new() se genera una nueva referencia. Si sacaras del bucle `servivo A = new servivo();` tu objeto `A` estará apuntando siempre a la misma dirección de memoria, con lo que "machacarías" los valores en cada iteración. En cambio, si dentro del bucle haces el new() generas una referencia nueva. Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Bien ahi ahi entendi como va sobre escribiendo la misma direccion en memoria, y una variable tipo int y un vector tipo int como en el ejemplo 2 que escribi arriba como trabajan? por cierto muchas gracias!! por aclararme esa duda!!

Comment: El tipo `int` es un tipo por valor (`value type`), esto quiere decir que si se declara una variable `int` y se asigna el valor a otra variable `int`, se tendrán dos copias separadas de los valores, esto es, el contenido de una variable se copia en la otra por lo que si se modifica el valor de la primera variable, en la segunda su valor no cambia.

Comment: Te daria mas puntos si pudiera muchisimas gracias!!